# What is the way to delete A .CSV file immediately after reading

Tags: python, csv

So I have A code that's running through CMD like so : 
Python script.py textfile.csv

Inside the script i have something like this :

After its reading the .csv file I'm trying to delete the file from the location , Is that possible to write a code to delete a file that's attached to the Script ? or do i need to link it?

The code :

```
    rows = csv.reader(f,delimiter=",",lineterminator="\n")
apple = {}
        user['apple'] = row[0]
        user['name'] = row[1]
        users.append(apple)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete a CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29579448/how-to-delete-a-csv-file-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`os.remove("textfile.csv")` should work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os module and os.remove().

```
import os
os.remove("demofile.txt")
```

You can just put the location of the csv file inside the os.remove() function